# How to link bootstrap files in django template that were installed into static folder by bower?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bower

## motivation

I want to user **bower** (*grunt*) package of bootstrap in my django template folder. I am aware of [django-bootstrap3](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3) which ideally can be configured to use those "local"/deployed copies of bootstrap package.

For now, I need a plain example to work. So this is what I do

---

### step 1: layout.html

I take an *hello world* template **layout.html** (from **bootstrap** docs page) and put it into templates folder registered within my django project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This example is valid for precompiled package.

### step 2: bower

I run something like:

```
cd path/to/django/static/folder
bower install bootstrap
```

That creates a folder called **bower_components**

### step 3: linking

**?**

PS

I am currently looking at yeoman board [here](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/268) to check if what is discussed is also a solution for me.

Comment: I see now that the problem turned out to be trivial. Should I delete the question? I am a bit confused here. I am sure the question may repeat itself though..

Comment: What is less trivial though is using static files to pass to django-bootstrap3 settings..

Comment: It's not that trivial if you don't know where bower stores css (`bower_components/bootstrap/dist`). Your question and your answer helped me and may help others getting started with wedding javascript to django using bower (with or without `django-bower`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *[static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/)* as documented on django page

```
{% static "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" %}
```

### In detail,

Layout.html will be changed to (assuming django 1.6):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}title{% endblock %}</title>

    {% load staticfiles %}
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="{% static "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use [django-bower](https://github.com/nvbn/django-bower#usage) you don't need `"bower_components/"` in your `{% static %}` path.

Comment: Using this method if you customise bootstrap (e.g. by editing `variables.less`) won't these changes be lost when you update bootstrap using bower?